# c# - Replacing dates in a large file with a format usable by MySql for BulkLoad

Tags: c#, mysql, date, date-format

I am using MYSqlBulkLoader to load a text file into a mysql db table. However, the date format in the file is mm/dd/yyyy and MySql expects the date in yyyy-mm-dd format. What is the best and the fastest way to replace all the dates in the text file with a proper format ? Also, Is there a way to make MySql accept the date format mm/dd/yyyy ?

Comment: How did you wrote your bulk insert code? please show us.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

DateTime.ParseExact("11-24-2011", "mm-dd-yyyy").ToString ("yyyy-MM-dd")

Comment: But it's a bulk insert, how would he do it on-the-fly?

Comment: he could create a program with a little background worker with the logic to parse the file in c# and once done use the newly created file for the bulk insert
considering he provided only data what he wants this is kinda the limit you can go with help

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used [that class](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-programming-bulk-loader.html), but it seems that it cannot convert a type on the fly. So you really need to replace all incorrect formats witht the correct.

A simple approach is rewriting the text file, for example(assuming that it's a csv-file, the separator is comma and the date column is the first):

```
var newLines = File.ReadAllLines(path)
    .Select(l => l.Split(','))
    .Select(sp => new{ 
        dt = DateTime.ParseExact(sp[0],"MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
        rest = string.Join(",", sp.Skip(1))
     })
    .Select(x => string.Format("{0},{1}", x.dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), x.rest));
File.WriteAllLines(path, newLines);
```

However, the best and most efficient way is to avoid invalid date in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to regenerate your data text file with the proper date-format (yyyy-mm-dd)
 or to create some console app that would load that data text file into the memory, make the required formatting operation, save the file and than make your bulk insert.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. I figured one possible way. However I am not sure if this is the optimal way. Works for now. Please do let me know if there is a better way.

```
var newLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
  for (int i = 0;i<newLines.Length;i++)
    {
       Regex regex = new Regex(@"[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}");
          foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(newLines[i]))
           {
             string modifiedDate = DateTime.Parse(match.Value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
             newLines[i] = newLines[i].Replace(match.Value, modifiedDate);
            }
     }
 File.WriteAllLines(fileName, newLines);
```

Comment: If you know the date fields in advanced, it would be an overkill to use RegEx. Look at @Tim Schmelter code example.

Comment: I would see Tim's code as one of the least efficient possible. The Regex approach goes into the right direction. Just put parentheses around the date parts and then write the regex parts directly back in the correct format, without any conversion between DateTime and string.